# Prepend multiple data to beginning of Core Data (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Could someone give some guidance on how to **prepend** newly ingested data to Core Data in the correct index order?

I have Core Data with an attribute, `contentID`. The objects are listed as: **`5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0`**

I query a web database that pushes updates since the highest `contentID`, **`5`**, and it returns an array with updates: **`7, 6`**

If you simply append it to Core Data, the order will go: **`5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6`**

How do you **prepend** it to the front correctly?

And also how do you prepend it in the **correct order** so that when you prepend the first new object, **`7`**, and then prepend the second item, **6**, it doesn't go: **`6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0`**

Hope this makes sense... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should not concern yourself with the order in which objects are written to or stored in the database.  Instead, specify the sort order in which you wish to receive the data when you fetch it from the database.

The sort order for a fetch is determined by the `sortDescriptors` property of the `NSFetchRequest`.  Each `NSSortDescriptor` specifies the key to determine the order, and whether the results should be in ascending order (v. descending).

So when you perform a fetch, you should in your case specify:

```
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key:"contentID", ascending:false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
let fetchedResults = managedObjectContent.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]
```

Comment: Great description! Thank you. So in other words, I pull away from concerning myself with the idea of a literal order and instead, focus on sorting the data regardless of its perceived position amongst its siblings. I'll give it a shot and be back with the result.

Comment: I'm not sure how the code above fits in with what I have: let fetchedResults = managedObjectContent.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

Comment: The `executeFetchRequest` should be after the code in my answer.